# how can i disable the tooltips of the buttons on a flex 3 togglebuttonbar

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, tooltip, togglebuttonbar

I'm creating an flex 3 application with 3 togglebuttonbars. 
What i would like to do is disable the tooltip of the buttons on one togglebuttonbar.
Does anybody know how i can access the buttons on the togglebuttonbar to disable the tooltips?

I don't want to disable all the tooltips off the total application(ToolTipManager.enabled = false;).

I have set the tooltip of the togglebuttonbar to null but it doesn't disable the creation of the buttons within the togglebutttonbar.

does anybody know how i can disable the tooltips of the buttons on the togglebuttonbar?

DJ

Answer (score 2):

To disable toolTips on the ToggleButtonBar instance you should be able to set the toolTip property to null; which is it's default and it should show no toolTips.

If you want to specifically access buttons inside the toolTip, you'll have to loop over the ToggleButtonBar's children.  Something like this should do it:

```
for(var x: int = 0; x < toggleButtonBarInstance.numChildren; x++){
 toggleButtonBarInstance.getChildAt(x).toolTip = null;
}
```

There doesn't seem to be an easier way to access the buttons.